# How do I request external storage permission for Android 13?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, permissions, android-external-storage

We have a game that we developed on Unity. We need storage permission to install and play the OBB file. We don't need any other permissions other than this. Which permission should we use and how? As of Android 13, our application remains on a black screen on devices with Android 13 because the permission window does not appear.

We have come this far without any problems by using read and write external storage permissions. However, as of Android 13, this has changed.

Frankly, I don't know if we need these permissions just to install our obb file on the device and enable the game to open. Which permission is more suitable for us? Our game remains on a black screen on devices with Android 13.

Comment: Name full path of the directory where you wanna install your file.

Comment: `We need storage permission to install the OBB file.` Is it? Really? Why? Which permission exactly? Then where were you storing your file all the time? Full path please.

Comment: Show the code you use(d) to install the OBB file.

Comment: @blackapps to the same place as all other applications. We store it in the My Files - Obb folder. We do not specify a specific location

Comment: @blackapps Technically, I may not be able to provide you with the answers you want. I'm sorry for that. As far as I know, we do not specifically determine a location for obb. We want to extract the build as obb from the Unity build settings. We preferably choose the SD card option as the location where the OBB will be installed. Apart from this, we do not take any action regarding OBB.

Comment: `We store it in the My Files - Obb folder` Sorry i have no idea where that would be.. That is a path that does not exist on an Android device. Just name full path of the used directory to make things clear.

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/mu78vt3 @blackapps We store our OBB file here.

Comment: Did you use the Files app for that? It looks like it displays Android/obb directory on external storage. Full path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb. Your app has no access to that folder on Android 13+. Not even with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or SAF.

Comment: Also on Android 12 your app has no access.

Comment: We do not use any application for this. All obb applications are positioned this way on all devices. We do not interfere with or change it in any way.

Our obb file is installed properly. The permission popup is not shown on Android 13 devices when opening the game. That's why we stay on the black screen. The permission to access files popup is shown on all devices except Android 13. The game runs smoothly.

First of all, do we need any permission? Do we need to ask players for storage permission at launch just for our game to run? If the answer is yes, how can we do this on Android 13?

Comment: @blackapps Do you have any solution suggestions mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need external storage permission for your own files if you store them in the right place.

Place them in

- [Context.getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) (no permissions needed);
- or, if no sufficient space above (which shouldn't be the case, really), use [Context.getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) (no permissions needed since `KITKAT`).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I request external storage permission for Android 13?

Unclear which you have in mind. A READ or WRITE permission.

They do not exist for Android 13+ devices anymore.

You have WRITE permission by default in all public directories on external storage.

Once you created/wrote a file you are allowed to read it too.

You are not allowed to read other apps files unless you go for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or use SAF.

Comment: We have a racing game on Google Play. We just want our OBB file to be stored correctly.

We do not need to access files such as photos and audio from another application.

Currently, we are stuck on a black screen on all Android 13 devices because there is no permission to open the game.

Comment: I just want my OBB file to be stored and the device to allow players to run the game using that OBB file. There is no other permission I need. What permission do I need to ask for this?

Comment: Look at the subject of your post. What is it that you need?